# C++ callback v.s. vector return in a data structure traversal method?

Tags: c++, data-structures

In the following example, I've implemented two ways of traversing a data structure. One uses a result vector which implies copies while the other uses a callback.

Which of the two approaches is usually better to use in typical C++ applications? Said differently, does one solution have flaws/drawbacks?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Foo {
    vector<T> v;

    vector<T> query(T query) {
        vector<T> results;
        for (auto &k : v)
            if (match(query, k))
                results.push_back(k);
    }

    void query(T query, const std::function<void(T&)>&cb) {
        for (auto &k : v)
            if (match(query, k))
                cb(k);
    }
};

template<typename T>
void display(Foo<T> &foo, T &query) {
    for(auto el : foo.query(query))
       cout << el << endl;

    foo.query(query, [](T &el) {
        cout << el << endl;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would use the callback approach, but I would remove the `std::function` and replace it with a template type.  `std::function` uses type erasure and that requires dynamic allocation and a little bit of overhead.  A function template like

```
template<typename Callback>
void query(T query, const Callback& cb) {
    for (auto &k : v)
        if (match(query, k))
            cb(k);
}
```

will remove that overhead and still let you pass any function object you want to the function.

Comment: I thought about the template approach, but it is less clear for the intelli-sense. The developer could try to do `query(query, 42)` without any warning until build time. So it is a matter of readability vs performance...

Comment: @nowox In that case you can add SFINAE using `std::is_invocable` to make sure `Callback` is a type that is invocable for the parameters you want.